# DICOM Processing

Tags: image-processing

[image]I am trying to perform analysis of DICOM ultrasound images that have vascular flow rates.  I am a new user to MATLAB, and I am trying to generate a line to fit the flow curve and calculate an area under the curve.  Any resources would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  Can you include an example of such an image or a link to one (if you don't have the rep to include the image in your question) ?

Comment: I uploaded an image that i cleaned up today.